# I am not able to install Hyperledger Composer on Mac OS X

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I have OSX 10.12.6 with all dependency

When I am tryng to install composer-cli it throws following error

```
npm install -g composer-cli
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@1.0.0: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated crypto@0.0.3: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
/usr/local/bin/composer -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/cli.js

> fsevents@1.1.3 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fsevents
> node install

[fsevents] Success: "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fsevents/lib/binding/Release/node-v57-darwin-x64/fse.node" already installed
Pass --update-binary to reinstall or --build-from-source to recompile

> pkcs11js@1.0.10 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/pkcs11js
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/main.o
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=c++
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-stdlib=libc++’
c++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-stdlib=libc++’
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Configured with: ./configure --prefix=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac --with-gxx-include-dir=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac/gcc/include/c++ --bindir=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac/bin --datarootdir=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac/share --libdir=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac/lib --with-gmp=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac --with-mpfr=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac --with-mpc=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac --with-isl=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac --with-cloog=/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac --with-boot-ldflags='-Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-L/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac/lib -Wl,-L/usr/lib' --with-stage1-ldflags='-Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -Wl,-L/Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_plac/lib -Wl,-L/usr/lib' --enable-checking=release --with-tune=generic --disable-multilib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 (GCC) 
make: *** [Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/main.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 16.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/pkcs11js
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pkcs11js@1.0.10 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pkcs11js@1.0.10 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ketan/.npm/_logs/2017-11-28T10_36_54_081Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be compiling the native modules with gcc rather than Apple XCode. You need to install XCode to compile native modules on Mac.

On my system I see:

```
node-gyp rebuild

gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
gyp WARN download NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR is deprecated and will be removed in node-gyp v4, please use NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/main.o
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
 "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.7.0 -Wdeprecated-objc-isa-usage -Werror=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -emit-obj -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -discard-value-names -main-file-name main.cpp -mrelocation-model pic -pic-level 2 -mthread-model posix -mdisable-fp-elim -fno-strict-return -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 302.3.1 -v -dwarf-column-info -debug-info-kind=standalone -dwarf-version=2 -debugger-tuning=lldb -coverage-notes-file /Users/dselman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/pkcs11js/build/Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/main.gcno -resource-dir /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0 -dependency-file ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/main.o.d.raw -MT Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/main.o -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.13.sdk -D NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME=pkcs11 -D USING_UV_SHARED=1 -D USING_V8_SHARED=1 -D V8_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS=1 -D _DARWIN_USE_64_BIT_INODE=1 -D _LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D _FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION -I /Users/dselman/.node-gyp/8.9.1/include/node -I /Users/dselman/.node-gyp/8.9.1/src -I /Users/dselman/.node-gyp/8.9.1/deps/uv/include -I /Users/dselman/.node-gyp/8.9.1/deps/v8/include -I ../../nan -I ../includes -I/usr/local/include -stdlib=libc++ -stdlib=libc++ -Os -Wall -Wendif-labels -W -Wno-unused-parameter -std=c++11 -fdeprecated-macro -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/dselman/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.1/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/pkcs11js/build -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 238 -stack-protector 1 -fblocks -fno-rtti -fno-threadsafe-statics -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.7.0 -fencode-extended-block-signature -fcxx-exceptions -fexceptions -fmax-type-align=16 -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -o Release/obj.target/pkcs11/src/main.o -x c++ ../src/main.cpp
clang -cc1 version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38) default target x86_64-apple-darwin17.2.0
```

Comment: I have Xcode 9.1 installed now I don't know how to change default gcc. Can you please help me

Comment: Maybe this information from your post will help you work out what is installed on your machine. /Users/ray/mc-x64-3.5/conda-bld/gcc-4.8_1477649012852

Comment: @david_k Thank You david it works. I just change path of GCC using following command and everything works
export PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following option to run the npm install success in the previous command.

```
npm install -g composer-cli  --unsafe-perm
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MacPorts in your PATH environment of your `.bash_profile` file, you can disable it to avoid that issue. You can verify if the correct compiler is working typing (below is my output):

```
Gironda-MacBook:Gironda$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

Sometimes even if we installed the Apple XCode correctly, the PATH environment cause that issue. Now you can also use `npm install -g composer-cli@X.X.X`. But be careful if you won't need to adapt anymore your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.